# Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityDisabledException: ReceiveDisabled

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-servicebus-queues

I have changed the Azure Service Bus Queue status from **Active** to **ReceiveDisabled**. Because I don’t want to process whenever message available in the queue. i.e. reason I have changed status to **ReceiveDisabled**.

After I changed the queue status to **ReceiveDisabled**, then I’m not able to post any message to that queue because I’m getting the below error.

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.MessagingEntityDisabledException: Messaging entity 'sb://xxx-xxx-xxx.servicebus.windows.net/test-queue' is currently disabled

.Net Core code to change the queue status:

```
var serviceBusManagementClient = new ManagementClient(_serviceBusSettings.Connection);
                foreach (var queueItem in queueItems)
                {
                    var queueDescription = await serviceBusManagementClient.GetQueueAsync(queueItem.Value);
                    queueDescription.Status = EntityStatus.ReceiveDisabled;
                    await serviceBusManagementClient.UpdateQueueAsync(queueDescription);
                }
```

.Net Core code to post messages to queue.

```
    var messageSender = new MessageSender(serviceBusSettings.Connection, serviceBusSettings.MainQueueName);
    var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(id))
                {
                    //Assign a SessionId for the message
                    MessageId = id
                };
              
                // Send a message corresponding to this sessionId to the queue
                messageSender.SendAsync(message);
```

I’m using the below references.

> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus
>
> Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Management

Reference documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/entity-suspend

So, how can I post messages to Queue which is having ReceiveDisabled status?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You called "receivedisabled" and are wondering why your queue does not receive any messages anymore?! ;-) You might be misunderstanding that "receive" here does not refer to your receiver (i.e. processor) but to the queue. If you dont want to process any messages anymore, just stop your processor?!

Comment: @silent, In production it is difficult to stop processor. So, instead of stopping processor I changed Queue status to ReceiveDisabled.

Comment: well but as you found out now, ReceiveDisabled is not what you want. So you need some logic in your processor to stop taking messages from the queue

Comment: @silent, Ok, but generally the meaning of this status is the queue is partially suspended, with send being permitted.

Comment: ok sorry, I finally got your point. my bad! and yes, I could repro it. there's something weird going on. When you set the status to SendDisabled you get a correct message "Queue is currently disabled for Send operations". But for ReceiveDisable you just get "Queue is disabled". I'll open an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Comment: Issue is here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10535

Comment: Thanks for update @silent

Comment: I have helpfully downvoted this question as a reminder that we prefer posts to be made without a signature. I have made this edit several times on your posts before. Please try to refrain from adding this to your future posts. Thank you!

Comment: @Pradeep see in the GitHub issue. The issue was now fixed in the service and is being rolled out :) thanks again for raising this!